# List.Contains strange behavior

Tags: c#, list, error-handling

I don't know if I'm missing something here but isn't it strange that my code below always raises an exception on List.Contains part although I know for sure that list contain that element:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class SomeClass
{
  public string param1 {get; private set;}
  public string param2 {get; private set;}

  private SomeClass(){}
  public SomeClass(string param1, string param2)
  {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
  }
}

class SomeClass2
{
  private List<SomeClass> myList = new List<SomeClass>();

  public void Add(SomeClass someclass)
  {
    myList.Add(someclass);
  }

  public void Remove(SomeClass someClass)
  {
    // this part always rises an exception
    if(!myList.Contains(someClass))
      throw new System.ArgumentException("some error");
    else myList.Remove(someClass);
  }
}

class MainClass
{
  public static void Main (string[] args)
  {
    var _someClass = new SomeClass2();          
    _someClass.Add(new SomeClass("aaa", "bbb"));

    try
    {
      _someClass.Remove(new SomeClass("aaa", "bbb"));   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Something is fishy here.  I don't have a compiler installed on this computer yet, but I'm going to install one because I don't see how your example compiles.

Comment: Sorry for the noise, I couldn't tell the difference between a pair of constructors and a class definition without a compiler...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) of the `Contains` method:

> This method determines equality by using the default equality
>   comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the
>   IEquatable(Of T).Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).

So you could implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) on your objects if you want the Contains method to determine if 2 instances of `SomeClass` are equal:

```
class SomeClass: IEquatable<SomeClass>
{
    public string param1 { get; private set; }
    public string param2 { get; private set; }

    private SomeClass() { }
    public SomeClass(string param1, string param2)
    {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    public bool Equals(SomeClass other)
    {
        return param1 == other.param1 && param2 == other.param2;
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to implement a custom [`EqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx):

```
class SomeClassEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeClass>
{
    private static readonly SomeClassEqualityComparer _instance = new SomeClassEqualityComparer();

    public bool Equals(SomeClass x, SomeClass y)
    {
        return x.param1 == y.param1 && x.param2 == y.param2;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeClass obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.param1.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.param2.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<SomeClass> Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }
}
```

and then use the following overload of the Contains method:

```
if (!myList.Contains(someClass, SomeClassEqualityComparer.Instance))
    throw new System.ArgumentException("some error");
```

Comment: Didn't notice that detail :/ Thanks

Comment: Well, that was a long way of saying  `deriving (Eq)` :D

Comment: Using the IEqualityComparer would seem to make SomeClass less useful taken by itself.  Then again, if you've got a whole lot of someclasses and can write an efficient enough IEqualityComparer (vanilla reflection probably wouldn't cut it) you might be able to save either some dev effort or pcode fetch time.

Answer (score 0):

You're not removing the same instance of SomeClass.  This will work:

```
public static void Main ()
{
    var _someClass = new SomeClass2();

    var someClass = new SomeClass("aaa", "bbb");
    _someClass.Add(someClass);

    try
    {
        _someClass.Remove(someClass); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

To make your original code work you would need to implement IEquatable.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't spend more time on the hash code implementation.  I don't even remember if ^ is the right xor operator...  I suppose I could rot13 before the xor, but that seemed kinda silly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DoesItCompile
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        private object param1;
        private object param2;
        private SomeClass() { }
        public SomeClass(string param1, string param2)
        {
            this.param1 = param1;
            this.param2 = param2;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object oThat)
        {
            if (!(oThat is SomeClass))
                return false;
            SomeClass scThat = (SomeClass)oThat;
            if (!string.Equals(this.param1, scThat.param1))
                return false;
            if (!string.Equals(this.param2, scThat.param2))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.param1.GetHashCode() ^ this.param2.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    class SomeClass2
    {
        private List<SomeClass> myList = new List<SomeClass>();

        public void Add(SomeClass someclass)
        {
            myList.Add(someclass);
        }

        public void Remove(SomeClass someClass)
        {
            // this part always rises an exception
            if (!myList.Contains(someClass))
                throw new System.ArgumentException("some error");

            else myList.Remove(someClass);
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var _someClass = new SomeClass2();

            _someClass.Add(new SomeClass("aaa", "bbb"));

            try
            {
                _someClass.Remove(new SomeClass("aaa", "bbb"));

                Console.WriteLine("Have a nice president's day.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. - I've no clue why you brought Zelda's stalker into the question, but I'm sure there's a good reason.